# Add new right click-new options?

Tags: windows, right-click, context-menu

Whenever I need to create a C, C++, Batch, HTML, or Javascript file I need to open a new text document and save it with a different file extension.  Is there a way I can add a new option to the Right Click->New menu (on a Windows computer) so that I can create a new program file directly from there?

Thanks
-Zach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file, add the content below, save it as *whatever.reg*, and run it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.php\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
```

**Note:** Replace `.php` with the file extension you want.

[image]

I believe this should work for you.